# Why does a simple React Component render twice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just started a new create-react-app project and noticed that react is rendering components twice! My react version in *package.json* is `"react": "^16.13.1"`

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const renders = useRef(0);
  console.log("renders: ", renders.current++);

  return (
    <div>
      Hello
    </div>
  );
};
```

This produces on first render:

```
renders: 0
renders: 0
```

Now if I add a button to increment state, each state change also produces two additional renders:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const renders = useRef(0);
  console.log("renders: ", renders.current++);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>increment</button>
      <div>count: {count}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

This will result in:

```
//--- initial render
renders: 0
renders: 0
//--- first click
renders: 1
renders: 2
//--- second click
renders: 3
renders: 4
//--- third click
renders: 5
renders: 6
```

Is this normal or is this a bug in the latest version of react?

Comment: It's because of strict mode. So, it will run twice in development not in production.

Comment: Yeah I realized this after some additional research. Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OK looks like I found out the reason. After inspecting `index.js` I found the following:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Looks like create-react-app now includes `React.StrictMode` which double invokes certain methods in development mode (not in production).

Comment: And it's a feature to make some hidden bugs explicit: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15074#issuecomment-471197572

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the StrictMode issue you found, I think when you're using a `ref` like that it creates a side-effect so you'd typically need to put it in `useEffect` to prevent it from rendering twice:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const renders = useRef(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    // Every time the component has been re-rendered,
    // the counter is incremented
    console.log("renders: ", renders.current++);
  }); 


  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>increment</button>
      <div>count: {count}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```